# Jenkins Extended email notification - set logged in user as the sender

Tags: jenkins

I would like the from address in the extended email notification of a job to be the user who is currently logged in. I have set a default suffix (@domainname.com) in the smtp configuration. But I couldn't default the sender email address as the person who is logged in. Is there a way to configure this?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these plugins, they do exactly what you need:

[Build User Vars Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+User+Vars+Plugin)

[Job Exporter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+Exporter+Plugin)

Comment: Lawicko - The Build User Vars plugin just sets the build user's details in the environmental variables. But I need to use the build user as the sender of an email. Unfortunately, the sender's email addresses can only be set globally from the Jenkins location section under Configure Jenkins menu (System Admin e-mail address). Is there a way to change this per job and also dynamically derive the information from the logged in user?